# Mass Assignment in model and rake tasks in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I recently upgraded my app from rails 3.2.13 to 4. I have been moving all mass assignment code using attr_accessible in models to strong parameters in controller. Some of the code belongs to model so I cant move them inside a controller hence cant use srong parameters. Is there any way I can deal with mass assignment in models without using protected_attributes gem? Does rails 4 have some specific fallback for these cases without going the old way of attr_accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`protected_attributes` gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes). It's however advised to create service/form objects to deal with params, because models should have no knowledge about them.